# Mutex without priority inheritance in C, what's the use?

Tags: c, mutex, thread-priority

In many projects over many years using RTOSs and mutexes, I confess I have never considered consciously using a mutex without priority inheritance (or ceiling, whichever is available).  Assuming the option is available, e.g. in ThreadX where mutexes can be had with or without priority inheritance, why would anyone disable priority inheritance except for maybe a small (miniscule, in most cases) difference in performance?  Seems like whenever you have a need to use a mutex, there is usually (always?) the chance of a priority inversion no matter how careful your design is, so what reason would anyone have for disabling the best tools for mitigating it?

Comment: Usually because you know (by design) that *every* thread that accesses the mutex has the same priority.  If that is the case, then priority inversion can't happen, so there's no point to the overhead.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris.  Having multiple threads share the same priority is a relatively rare occurrence in the projects I've worked on.  Almost always, some threads are identified as more critical than others and get a correspondingly higher priority.  Are there any other reasons for not using priority inheritance?  Is the difference in overhead really that significant?

Comment: @CJClegg I guess PI mutex also implies it not only does priority boosting, bit is also fair (otherwise there is no point). Check [this](https://blog.mozilla.org/nfroyd/2017/03/29/on-mutex-performance-part-1/). It shows that on MacOS there is 10 times difference between fair and unfair mutexes.

Comment: Most applications are not real-time in a sense that they are more concerned with throughput than latency, so priority inversion is not really an issue (as number of work-units per second is usually not damaged by it).